# Simple Proof that a Reductive Group is Unimodular?

Tags: algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a connected, reductive group over a local field $k$ of characteristic zero.  I thought of a simple proof that $G(k)$ is unimodular, but I realize it is almost certainly wrong: $G(k)$ is generated by its derived group and its center, and the modular character is trivial on both of these, Q.E.D.

I am relying on some results from algebraic groups over algebraically closed fields which I am not certain carry over to arbitrary fields.  So what I wanted to know which of these results are false for arbitrary $k$ (all being true in the case $k = \overline{k}$)

-$[G,G](k) = [G(k),G(k)]$

-$Z(G)(k) = Z(G(k))$

-$G(k)$ is generated by $[G,G](k)$ and $Z(G)(k)$

Moreover, can the idea of this proof be modified to correctly show that $G(k)$ is modular?

Comment: It is not true that $G(k)$ is generated by $(\mathscr{D}G)(k)$ and $(Z_G)(k)$; this fails for $G = {\rm{GL}}_n$ since $\det: {\rm{GL}}_n \rightarrow \mathbf{G}_m$ is surjective on $k$-points but kills $({\rm{SL}}_n)(k)$ and carries $(Z_{{\rm{GL}}_n})(k)$ onto $(k^{\times})^n$.  The idea works over all local fields (char. 0 not relevant) because the modulus character is the absolute value of an actual algebraic character defined in an evident manner, and one can test vanishing of that algebraic character on geometric points, where your idea works; see Prop. 4 & Prop. 5 in 4.2 of *Neron Models*.

Comment: It's enough if instead one shows that $G(k)/\overline{DG(k)Z_G(k)}$ is compact.

Comment: I think the latter approach works in arbitrary characteristic, but is more difficult than the one in my answer (I don't remember how one gets this compactness result).

Comment: Another merit of the algebraic modulus character is that it gives the unimodularity on adelic points in the global case by exactly the same argument without needing to mess around with product measures or integral models at all but finitely many places (though one could avoid it via unimodularity over each local field). The algebraic modulus character is like The Force: it binds the galaxy (of measures across all local field extensions) together. It also conceptually explains "algebraicity" of formulas for the modulus character seen in all examples, which can't be explained by analytic means.

Comment: @YCor: That $(DG)(k)Z_G(k)$ is closed and cocompact in $G(k)$ for connected reductive $G$ over any non-archimedean local field $k$ (so no need for form closures) is explained in the answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134783/how-to-translate-the-representation-theory-of-semisimple-to-reductive-groups?rq=1

Comment: Also, though now moot, of the 1st and 2nd equalities you ask about (we saw the 3rd is often false), the 2nd is true over any infinite field since $G(k)$ is Zariski-dense (and hence schematically dense) in $G$ due to unirationality of $G$ over $k$ (valid over any field), whereas the 1st often fails even in the semisimple case: if $q:\widetilde{G}\to G$ is the simply connected central cover then the commutator map of schemes $G \times G \rightarrow G$ factors through $q$, so $[G(k),G(k)]\subset q(\widetilde{G}(k))$, and $q$ is essentially never surjective on $k$-points (e.g., ${\rm{PGL}}_n$).

Answer (score 11):

The modular character $\Delta: G(k)\rightarrow {\mathbb R}_{>0}$ on $G(k)$ is trivial on the commutator subgroup and is trivial on a compact open subgroup and also on the centre. These three groups generate a subgroup of finite index since the abeliansation of $G(k)$ modulo centre is compact. Hence the modular character is trivial on an open subgroup of finite index, and is hence trivial. This works in arbitrary characteristic.

I am sure that I have seen this argument somewhere in the literature, but old age and failing memory prevent me from recalling the reference.

Answer (score 5):

Since you assume that $k$ has characteristic zero, one can make use of the Lie algebra. If $G$ is an arbitrary Lie group over a locally compact field $k$ of characteristic zero, $G$ is unimodular if and only of the adjoint action of $G$ on its Lie algebra is by elements of determinant of modulus 1. In the case of $G=\mathbb{G}_k$, with $\mathbb{G}$ reductive connected, the Lie algebra has the form $\mathfrak{s}\oplus\mathfrak{z}$ with $\mathfrak{s}$ semisimple and $\mathfrak{z}$ central, and the adjoint $G$-action preserves this decomposition and is trivial on $\mathfrak{z}$. Moreover the automorphism group of $\mathbb{s}$ has a finite index subgroup acting with determinant 1 (because self-derivations of $\mathfrak{s}$ are inner and have trace zero because $\mathfrak{s}$ is perfect). This entails the unimodularity statement.